# Add expand button to datagridview

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, datagridview, treeview

I have a datagridivew dgvA which contains 2 columns {A,B}.
I want to add the expand button to the column {A} if a condition is met, and when it is expanded, another Dgv will unveil to show more records.

an example is as follows
[image]

Expanded:-

[image]
How would one go about this ? I mean the part of adding a button and a text to a the first column cells is new to me, not to mention that each is aligned on one side of the cell.

Comment: Here's one I've shared before: [Master-Detail DataGridView](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/835501/master-detail-datagridview). You can use a converter such as the [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) for most of the VB to C# conversion.